# Using switch statements inside a for loop

Tags: java

I have a question about weather it's legal to use a switch statement inside a for loop. The way its written below Eclipse gives me an error and won't let me use switch(n) on the second statement in the for loop. What I want to do is write...

This old man, he played 1 
He played knick-knack on my thumb.

Is there a better way of solving the problem below with a for loop and switch statement? I want to write out the paragraphs 10 different with the different number and different case. So 1 thumb, 2 shoe, 3 knee.... until 10.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class SingSong extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
            println("This old man, he played " + n);
            println("He played knick-knack on my" + switch(n));
            println("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack,");
            println("Give your dog a bone");
            println("This old man came rolling home");

            switch (n) {            
                case 1 : println("thumb"); break;
                case 2 : println("shoe"); break;
                case 3 : println("knee"); break;
                case 4 : println("door"); break;
                case 5 : println("hive"); break;
                case 6 : println("sticks"); break;
                case 7 : println("heaven"); break;
                case 8 : println ("pate"); break;
                case 9 : println("spine"); break;
                case 10 : println("shin"); break; 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Eclipse gives me an error.' Which error in detail?

Comment: the error is ...syntax error on token "+", ++ expected

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm reading all the suggestions and trying them out right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is a method you'll call:

```
private String which(int n) {
  switch (n) {
  case 1 : return "thumb";
  case 2 : return "show";
  case 3 : return "knee";
  case 4 : return "door";
  case 5 : return "hive";
  case 6 : return "sticks";
  case 7 : return "heaven";
  case 8 : return "pate";
  case 9 : return "spine";
  case 10 : return "shin";
  default: return "";

  }
}
```

Then replace

```
println("He played knick-knack on my" + switch(n));
```

with

```
println("He played knick-knack on my" + which(n));
```

Another, more succint approach would be to create an array of strings:

```
static final String[] which = {
  "thumb","show","knee","door","hive", "sticks","heaven","pate","spine","shin"};
```

and then just use

```
println("He played knick-knack on my" + which[n]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Creating methods is actually the next chapter.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `Map<Integer, String>` containg the integer to string mapping and use `Map.get()` to obtain the string:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
m.put(1, "thumb");
// etc
m.put(10, "shin");

println("He played knick-knack on my" + m.get(n));
```

Comment: thanks but I have not learned maps yet. So I have to stick with the material I've learned so far which are for loops, switch statements and else/else if.

Answer (score 3):

```
    println("He played knick-knack on my" + switch(n));
```

this wouldnt make a call to your Switch. switch is not a method. 
in order to  get the desired output,

```
println("This old man, he played " + n);
            println("He played knick-knack on my" );

    switch (n){

            case 1 : print("thumb"); break;
            case 2 : println("shoe"); break;
            case 3 : println("knee"); break;
            case 4 : println("door"); break;
            case 5 : println("hive"); break;
            case 6 : println("sticks"); break;
            case 7 : println("heaven"); break;
            case 8 : println ("pate"); break;
            case 9 : println("spine"); break;
            case 10 : println("shin"); break; 

            }
```

Or even better follow @Marko Topolnik approach, which i would say is the best approach .

Answer (score 1):

SWitch(n) is not a function and cannot be used as such. To the compiler this is like starting a switch statement but doing it completely wrong and thus it returns an error. I think to do this correctly you should put the case switch in a different method, or put it directly after the second line. Like this:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class SingSong extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run(){
for ( int n = 1; n <= 10; n++){

    println("This old man, he played " + n);
    print("He played knick-knack on my ");
    switch (n){
    case 1 : print("thumb"); break;
    case 2 : print("show"); break;
    case 3 : print("knee"); break;
    case 4 : print("door"); break;
    case 5 : print("hive"); break;
    case 6 : print("sticks"); break;
    case 7 : print("heaven"); break;
    case 8 : print("pate"); break;
    case 9 : print("spine"); break;
    case 10 : print("shin"); break; 
    }
    println("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack,");
    println("Give your dog a bone");
    println("This old man came roiling home");

      } 
       }

      }
```

This should work. Or put it in a different method:

```
 import acm.program.*;


public class SingSong extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run(){

for ( int n = 1; n <= 10; n++){

    println("This old man, he played " + n);
    print("He played knick-knack on my");
    switcher(n);
    print("\n");
    println("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack,");
    println("Give your dog a bone");
    println("This old man came roiling home");
}
}

    private void switcher(int n){
    switch(n){
    case 1 : print("thumb"); break;
    case 2 : print("show"); break;
    case 3 : print("knee"); break;
    case 4 : print("door"); break;
    case 5 : print("hive"); break;
    case 6 : print("sticks"); break;
    case 7 : print("heaven"); break;
    case 8 : print ("pate"); break;
    case 9 : print("spine"); break;
    case 10 : print("shin"); break; 


      } 
       }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
println("He played knick-knack on my" + switch(n));
```

if you want your code largely the same, you should delegate to a method performing the switch.

Alternative solutions would include a sequence of `if`/`else if` (somewhat verbose), or perhaps an array acting as a lookup table.

e.g.

```
// note arrays are indexed from 0
String[] arrayOfObjects = new String[]{"thumb", ....};
println("He played knick-knack on my" + arrayOfObjects(n-1));
```

I think perhaps a `Map` is overkill in this situation unless you have non-contiguous indexing (unlikely)

Comment: I figured that the problem was much simpler. It was supposed to be solved by using a if/else if approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `switch` like a method. Do following changes and it'll work:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class SingSong extends ConsoleProgram 
{
    public void run()
    {
        for ( int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
        {
            println("This old man, he played " + n);
            println("He played knick-knack on my" + getValue(n));
            println("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack,");
            println("Give your dog a bone");
            println("This old man came roiling home");
        }
    }

    private String getValue(int n)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : return "thumb"; break;
            case 2 : return "shoe"; break;
            case 3 : return "knee"; break;
            case 4 : return "door"; break;
            case 5 : return "hive"; break;
            case 6 : return "sticks"; break;
            case 7 : return "heaven"; break;
            case 8 : return "pate"; break;
            case 9 : return "spine"; break;
            case 10 : return "shin"; break;

            default : return "VALUE NOT FOUND!!";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have not yet learned about creating our own methods. The book wanted us to use if/else if approach to solve the problem. It was really much simpler to solve than the approach i took using the  for/switch approach.

Answer (score -2):

The switch/case statement inside of a for loop is fine, the problem is that switch isn't a function call. Try something like this:

```
    string obj;
    switch (n){

    case 1 : obj="thumb"; break;
    case 2 : obj="show"; break;
    //Etc
    }


    }
    println("This old man, he played " + n);
    println("He played knick-knack on my" + obj);
    println("With a knick-knack, paddy-whack,");
    println("Give your dog a bone");
    println("This old man came roiling home");
```