# Run multiple classes with netbeans maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have one Maven project in Netbeans, which has several classes, which contain a main method.

Is there a way to run different classes with a shortcut? I mean something like the different run configurations in Eclipse, which offers me a dropdown.

I found out that I can specify different main classes, if I add several configurations in NetBeans. But for me it is not very convenient if I have to set the configuration to A and press run, set the configuration to B and press run and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't actually answers the question in the manner you want but this could be one of the workaround solution.

1. Create a separate class having a main method.
2. It has a main method that calls main function of each of the classes (you want to run) using Switch-Case.
3. Put this switch case in a loop with an exit switch.

link to achieve step 3. [Using switch statements inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378183/using-switch-statements-inside-a-for-loop)

Note: Visibility of classes can be an issue.